# FLUTTER: StreamBuilder only building last Snapshot, yield not yielding previous Snapshots

Tags: flutter, stream, yield

So I have various records cached in Sembast database.

I'm trying to retrieve those that match Ids from `List<String> bookmarkedJobIds`

Print logs show I am doing this, however the for loop inside `Stream<Job> getBookmarkedJobs()` doesn't yield after extracting each record.  The for loops runs through all the records in the list, extracting them, then the yield simply returns the last record extracted.  So in `build` I only get one card built.

I don't know why this is, or how to solve it.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    initialiseLocalStorage();
    jobStream = controller.stream;
    controller.addStream(getBookmarkedJobs());
  }

  Stream<Job> getBookmarkedJobs() async* {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bookmarkedJobIds = prefs.getStringList("bookmarks");
    if (bookmarkedJobIds == null) yield null;
    for (String bookmarkedJobId in bookmarkedJobIds) {
      Job job = await JobDao().retrieve(bookmarkedJobId);
      print('retrieved job, extracting employerName: ${job.employerName}');
      yield job;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('INSIDE BOOKMARKED BUILD');
    return StreamBuilder<Job>(
      stream: jobStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Job> snapshot) {
```

Comment: so most likely you need `Stream<List<Job>>` (or `Stream<Iterable<Job>>`)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts pskink, that's an alternative direction I think, returning a list or an Iterable I could then iterate over in build.  As I understand it a Stream should output a series of records, in this instance Job records, this seems to me the best pattern generally because it'll often get records to the display faster.  I don't understand why getBookmarkedJobs() doesn't yield a job to StreamBuilder every iteration of it's containing For loop.  Again appreciated your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @pskink kind attention, I've converted the `StreamBuilder` to `ListView.builder`, I wanted to use Stream just to make my app consistent, make the Firebase processing similar to the internal cache processing using Sembast, but I think retrieving from a device database rather than the cloud is more reliable.

Using a ListView means I gathered all the data I need into a list in my `init()` method then pump it through a ListView in `build`, there's no reason to believe you're going to get subsequent shots of records arriving arbitrarily, which is StreamBuilder's specialism.

Having studied a bit more I've found that sample apps sometimes have a parent StreamBuilder then hand the record SnapShots over to a child ListView.builder.  So ListView is not like yesterday's clumsy Widget fading into obsolescence.

Comment: Can you share some example, please?